# Creating a local storage for HTML form

Tags: html, forms, storage, local

I want to start a questionnaire/form project that saves the form data locally. I don't have any server or anything installed, I am just working off a local HTML file and would like to get the answers from the form to be sent into any form of a text file. Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline script in your HTML and use the `localStorage` object.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target"></div>
        <script>
            localStorage.setItem("name", "Dan");
            var name = localStorage.getItem("name);
            document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = name;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```